# Matlab implementation of Needleman-Wunsch algorithm

Tags: algorithm, strings, pathfinding, matlab, edit-distance

This code (an implementation of the path finding Needleman-Wunsch algorithm), given two sequences, correctly aligns and calculates the similarity of them. For example, given two sequences:

> AAA,CCC

or

> AA,CA

it correctly aligns them as

> ```
> ---AAA
> CCC---
> ```

and

> ```
> -AA
> CA-
> ```

respectively, while returning the similarity.

```
% Matlab implementation of NW algorithm
% Written by Joseph Farah
% Completed 7/14/16
% Last updated 7/14/16
function similarity = needleman(s1, s2)
% defining variables
% sequence related variables
s1 = strcat('-',s1);
s2 = strcat('-',s2);
seq1 = s1;
seq2 = s2;
%seq1 = '-ACTTAGATTACTTG';
%seq2 = '-CCCACTAGATTATTAG';
fseq1 = '';
fseq2 = '';
% weights
w_s = 2;
w_indel = 1;
% temporary costs for the matrix fill
h_cost = 0;
v_cost = 0;
d_cost = 0;
% the matrices
cost_matrix = zeros(length(seq1),length(seq2));
direction_cell_matrix = cell(length(seq1),length(seq2));
%% Initiliazation and Scoring
for x = 1:length(seq1)
    for y = 1:length(seq2)
        point = [seq1(x), seq2(y)];
        if point(1) == '-' && point(2) == '-'
            cost_matrix(x,y) = 0;
            direction_cell_matrix{x,y} = 'n';
            continue
        end
        % apparently, to get it to go in the right order, moving
        % horizontally is defined by y-1 and vertically by x-1
        if point(1) == '-' % this means it is on the lip -- 
            cost_matrix(x,y) = cost_matrix(x,y-1) + w_indel;
            % the only way it can go is left!
            direction_cell_matrix{x,y} = 'h';
            continue
        end
        if point(2) == '-' % is it vertical?
            cost_matrix(x,y) = cost_matrix(x-1,y) + w_indel;
            % the only way it can go is up!
            direction_cell_matrix{x,y} = 'v';
            continue
        end
        % if none of the above conditions were met, the point must be in
        % the body of the array. First thing we have to do is calculate the
        % cost of the current point. 
        h_cost = cost_matrix(x,y-1) + w_indel;
        v_cost = cost_matrix(x-1,y) + w_indel;
        % the diagonal cost will be determined by this next bit--do the
        % characters match?
        if point(1) == point(2)
            % if they match, there is no cost!
            d_cost = cost_matrix(x-1,y-1) + 0;
        elseif point(1) ~= point(2)
            % if they are a mismatch, the cost is the subsitution weight
            d_cost = cost_matrix(x-1,y-1) + w_s;
        end
        % now lets compare them! time to put them in a list...
        min_list_cost = [h_cost, v_cost, d_cost];
        minimum = min(min_list_cost);
        % now we have a cost, and we put it in the matrix!
        cost_matrix(x,y) = minimum;      
        % one last step-- we need to calculate the optimal direction
        % to do this, we have to find the minimum of the surround paths.
        % Back to the cost variables!
        h_cost = cost_matrix(x,y-1);
        v_cost = cost_matrix(x-1,y);
        d_cost = cost_matrix(x-1,y-1);
        % its important to keep track of the order, because the index of
        % the minimum value of the list will give us the correct direction 
        % for the point!
        min_list_direction = [h_cost, v_cost, d_cost];
        % now we find the minumum AND the index. Without the index, we
        % dont know which way to go!
        % minimum = min(min_list_direction);
        % now that we have a minumum, which direction is it in?
        % we went h, v, d
        index = find(min_list_cost == minimum);
        if index(1) == 1
            direction_cell_matrix{x,y} = 'h';
        elseif index(1) == 2
            direction_cell_matrix{x,y} = 'v';
        elseif index(1) == 3
            direction_cell_matrix{x,y} = 'd';
        end
    end
end
%%Traceback
% defining variables for how much we are deviating from the end point
% the final sequence at its worst will be as long as the first sequence
% plus the second sequence. The loop cannot go on for longer than that.
x = length(seq2);
y = length(seq1);
% the coordinate variables above will be updated so that moving through the
% direction matrix will match moving through the sequences
for ii = 1:(length(seq1)+length(seq2))
    if direction_cell_matrix{y,x} == 'n'
        break
    end 
    if direction_cell_matrix{y,x} == 'h'
        fseq2 = strcat(seq2(x),fseq2);
        fseq1 = strcat('-',fseq1);
        y = y;
        x = x - 1;
    elseif direction_cell_matrix{y,x} == 'v'
        fseq2 = strcat('-',fseq2);
        fseq1 = strcat(seq1(y),fseq1);
        y = y - 1;
        x = x;
    elseif direction_cell_matrix{y,x} == 'd'
        fseq2 = strcat(seq2(x),fseq2);
        fseq1 = strcat(seq1(y),fseq1);
        y = y - 1;
        x = x - 1;
    end
end
sim_score = 0;
for ii=1:length(fseq1)
    if fseq1(ii) == fseq2(ii)
        sim_score = sim_score + 1;
    else
        continue
    end
end
similarity = sim_score/length(fseq1);
```

What can I do to improve:

- Efficiency?
- Readability?
- the Matlab-iness of the code? (i.e where can I take advantage of tools Matlab has to offer?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll take this from the bottom up:

The last part of the code that calculates the similarity can be vectorized by comparing all elements of the two vectors and summing the ones that are equal:

```
sim_score = 0;
for ii=1:length(fseq1)
    if fseq1(ii) == fseq2(ii)
        sim_score = sim_score + 1;
    else
        continue
    end
end
similarity = sim_score/length(fseq1);
```

Can instead be written like this:

```
similarity = sum(fseq1 == fseq2) / numel(fseq1);
```

or if you want the `sim_score` too:

```
sim_score = sum(fseq1 == fseq);
similarity = sim_score / numel(fseq1);
```

Note that `numel` is faster and more robust than `length`.

Timing of loop approach versus vectorized approach:

[image]

---

You are using `strcat` a lot. `strcat` is good as it's easy to read and understand that you're concatenating strings (vector of characters). However, regular concatenating with brackets `[str1, str2]` is faster:

Instead of `fseq2 = strcat('-',fseq2);` you can do `fseq2 = ['-', fseq2]`.

Timing of `strcat` vs brackets:

[image]

---

You're using only the first elements of the `index` variable after calling `find`. `find` has a second optional parameter that specifies the number of indices you want to store, so you can do:

```
index = find(min_list_cost == minimum, 1);
if index == 1
   ...
if index == 2
   ...
```

Specifying that you only want the first index improve the runtime of up to 30%.

If you can safely assume that the equal elements appear in the start of the vectors, you're better of defining your own `find_first` function. This assumption is safe if you have a lot of repetitive elements, such as `AACCTTATTCTTA..`.

A *very* simple function that has runtime `O(1)` if the first equal value appear in the beginning of the vector.

```
function idx = find_first(x, val)

idx = 0;
for ii = 1:numel(x)
    if x(ii) == val
        idx = ii;
        break
    end
end
end
```